# Powershell Stop Services, defrg disks and then start services

Tags: powershell

Im trying to write a powershell script to stop services. WAIT for these services to stop and then run disk defrag for 4 disks and then run services again.
I tested the below but powershell keep performing step after step while i need powershell to wait until each step is finished to perform the next step.

```
Stop-Service -Name 'Service1' -Force
Stop-Serivce -Name 'Service2' -Force
Optmize-Volume -DriveLetter C -Defrag
Optmize-Volume -DriveLetter D -Defrag
Optmize-Volume -DriveLetter E -Defrag
Start-Service -Name 'Service1'
Start-Service -Name 'Serivce2'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use any loop to put script into sleep and check whether the previous task stopped (for services would be `(Get-Service "service1").Status -eq "Stopped"` but I don't have Win10 on hand to check how you can verify if `Optimize-Volume` has finished). Maybe running `Optimize-Volume` as job would do the trick (then you just need to check if job has finished).

Answer (score 0):

You can check the status of the service before executing the next command

```
Stop-Service -Name 'ServiceName' -Force
$serv = Get-service -Name 'ServiceName'
Write-Host $serv.Status
while ($serv.Status -ne "Stopped"){
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

}
```